# Can't import anything on Jupyter (python 3 version )

Tags: anaconda, jupyter

My Anaconda version is with python 2.7

I can import some module on my Ipython and on jupyter notebook with python 2

But why I open my jupyter notebook with python 3

I can't import anything ,like pandas ,numpy etc..

How can I install those package on my jupyter with python 3 version

Thank!!

Answer (score 0):

From the command line, you can install Python 3 packages using `pip3 install [package]`. This should allow Anaconda with Python 3 to use them.

Edit: Be sure to mark answers that were helpful to you.